# Split function to a String containing a '+' character

Tags: java, string

In split method if I pass only '+' character like this:

```
public class StringSplit {

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        String s1 = "test+plus";
        String[] stArr = s1.split("+");
        System.out.println(stArr.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < stArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(stArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The following error is coming:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1878)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2292)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2334)
    at StringSplit.main(StringSplit.java:5)
```

But if I replace the split call with:

```
String[] stArr = s1.split("\\+");
```

it is working fine.

Is there any reason why the behavior is this ?

Comment: Because the documentation says it is as such ..

Answer (score 7):

The split method treat the "+" as regular expression so + is basically an operator in regular expressions. If you use "\\+" then it takes it as character.

For reference please check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

Comment: +1 And since the backslash is also a special character, that would be `"\\+"`.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

The String.split method in Java takes a regular expression as input. As your error message says, the '+' character is a meta character. In particular, it says that the pattern before the '+' will be repeated 1 or more times. Of course you can escape the '+' with a backslash when you really mean a '+' character and not the meta character for repeating patterns, which is why s1.split("\+") works.